# Is it possible to morph sub-parts of image A using sub-parts of image B?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-ui, image-processing, morphing

I am trying to create my photo album. Now, my requirement is -I have one of my pics wearing casual t-shirt and jeans(consider this as image A). I also have downloaded another pic of a fashion model wearing armani suit (consider this as image B). Is it possible to morph my pic (image A) such that I am wearing that armani suit of fashion model (image B).

So, here I am talking about morph of sub-parts of images. Also, is it possible to adjust the suit (sub-part of image B) according to my height and width (property of image A), so that it doesn't look like morphed image??

If yes, which programming language is best suited based on reliability and performance?

I know this is a vague question, but any explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: List down what you have researched so far. It is certainly possible, but without any specific criteria/requirements your question is mostly seeking an opinion. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask specific questions after having done considerable research yourself.

Comment: @YogeshMangaj actually I tried couple of algorithms which transformed one image into other, but I wanted to transform only sub-parts of image A into sub-parts of image B with proper measurements, so wanted to ask if this is possible. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is not related to any programming language but to Computer Vision discipline. So try to search for algorithm which is close to your problem as much as possible. Then look at the popular libraries such as OpenCV (and binding for specific programming language).

Image recognition is a very complex task. Pay attention to details. For example, your trivial T-shirt has certain color which is homogeneous, etc. From the other side, fashion model is mixed-colored. And try to get more details about what your program should do. Depending on this you will spend several weeks or several years.

As for your question, yes, it is possible. But depending on concrete task details it can take a enormous effort.

Comment: I looked into the capabilities of OpenCV and seems like upto some part, it can do the job. Thanks @flaz14 for your suggestion.